# Destructuring assignment in while loop in ES6 function doesn't propogate out of loop?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, destructuring

I was implementing a simple GCD algorithm in ES6 (through node-esml) and came upon (to me) strange behaviour with updating values of variables inside a while loop. This code works fantastically:

```
function gcdWithTemp(x, y) {
  let [r, rdash] = [x, y]
  while (r != 0) {
    q = Math.floor(rdash / r)
    temp = r
    r = rdash - q * r
    rdash = temp
  }
  return(rdash)
}
console.log(gcdWithTemp(97, 34))
```

Returning the expected answer of `1`. However, if I remove the temporary variable and instead use destructuring assignment to try and achieve the same results:

```
function gcdWithDestructuredAssignment(x, y) {
  let [r, rdash] = [x, y]
  while (r != 0) {
    q = Math.floor(rdash / r)
    [r, rdash] = [rdash - q * r, r]
  }
  return(rdash)
}
console.log(gcdWithDestructuredAssignment(97, 34))
```

It never completes, further debugging shows that r will always have the first value assigned to, `x`. It seems that these two implementations should be identical? see [Swapping variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Swapping_variables)

I've also tried with using `var` instead of `let` to no avail. Am I drastically misunderstanding the point of destructuring assignment or missing something subtle? Or is it a bug?

Comment: Your `q` and `temp` variables are [implicitly global](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/03/horror-of-implicit-globals.html). Use strict mode!

Comment: Btw, why don't you just write `function gcd(r, rdash) {` and omit the `let [r, rdash] = [x, y]`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That's a problem not with destructuring assignment, but with ASI (automatic semicolon insertion). These two lines:

```
q = Math.floor(rdash / r)
[r, rdash] = [rdash - q * r, r]
```

in practice mean this:

```
q = Math.floor(rdash / r)[r, rdash] = [rdash - q * r, r]
```

which obviously is not what you meant. To fix that, add a semicolon in front of `[`:

```js
function gcdWithDestructuredAssignment(x, y) {
  let [r, rdash] = [x, y]
  while (r != 0) {
    q = Math.floor(rdash / r)
    ;[r, rdash] = [rdash - q * r, r]
  }
  return(rdash)
}
console.log(gcdWithDestructuredAssignment(97, 34))
```

Of course you can add the missing semicolon at the end of the previous line instead (`q = Math.floor(rdash / r);`), but since you generally don't use semicolons, I assumed that you're using [npm coding style](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/coding-style#semicolons).

Comment: Congrats for finding the missing semicolon, but why would you add it at the beginning of the second line rather than at the end of the first as is usual?

Comment: @Aaron It's [npm coding style](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/coding-style#semicolons).

Comment: Thanks, glad to learn that. It indeed makes sense to put the semicolon on the start of problematic lines if they're usually omitted and the problem is aggregation with the previous line whatever it is.